# Do not cross the line!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

Elliot and Terry *used* to be friends, until the fateful day when they played a round of that simple, unassuming game. Let’s just say that afterward there were no hugs and kisses to be found between the two...

> **Across**
>
> Give out punishment
>   Protagonists of many YA novels
>   Harbor protector
>
> **Down**
>
> Name that fades out of existence?
>   What atoms desire
>   Sugar or red item

**What game did they play? Who went first? And who eventually won the match, thus ruining their friendship?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the one who went first was

> Elliot

and the winner was

> also Elliot.

They played

> Tick-tack-toe with "E" and "T". (This is clued by "hugs and kisses", which refers to the use of "xoxo" in letters.)

Answers

> a1. Give out punishment = METE
>  a2. Protagonists of many YA novels = TEEN
>  a3. Harbor protector = JETTY
>  d1. Name that fades out of existence? = PETER
>  d2. What atoms desire = OCTETS
>  d3. Sugar or red item = BEET

Finished grid:

> [image]

Comment: You got it right! For A2 (and I guess D2 as well), there’s a small correction that should be made in order to make it fit the clue better. And there’s another hint in the title, can you spot it?

Comment: @PiIsNot3 Hmm... maybe [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toe_the_line)?

Comment: Hmm... rot13(abhtugf naq pebffrf -> abhtug pebff -> abg pebff)?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was going for; perhaps I made it a little too difficult to spot. Anyway, I’ll delete my previous comments and wait a bit before accepting this answer :)

Comment: That name is also a verb.

Comment: @BenJ Ah, now I get it. I thought it referred to its waning popularity... This makes way more sense. Thanks!